# Copy or not copy

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say we refer to documents that we have copies of. It's fine to say something like "this document has 2 copies" - that would mean that there is an original document + 2 copies of it.

But I've seen in some official notifications something like "**this document was drawn up in one copy**".
Is this grammatically correct ?
Because a copy implies that there are already 2 documents in existence. So that formulation used for documents emitted as only 1 exemplary does not seem correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Copy* can mean 'a single specimen of a book or other publication' - see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/copy . So 'there are two copies of this document' could mean that there exist two of them, not an original and two more. 'I have made two copies of the document you gave me' makes it clear that there are now three.